# Adding additional option under node publish options

Tags: views, hooks, users, nodes

In add /edit node page under publish options there are four option available

Published
Promoted to front page
Sticky at top of lists
Create new revision

Is there a possibility to add a 5th one for example Active and can use that option in views so that only the nodes which are they appear other nodes must not.

I am a themer not a coder so, I would really appreciate if your answer can also contain the code or reference or descriptive how to steps.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not precisely, but you could create a 'single checkbox' text field in your content and then filter on that value in Views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do it without adding the 5th option, if you familiar to [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) module, and Taxonomy module, you can simply add vocabulary(in Taxonomy configuration) and add Term - for example *Active*, next you can add field to your Content Type(Article or whatever) and now if you want to post an article you can chose - Active term.
Next step, create new view, add whatever you want(body, title, etc) and in Views/**Contextual filters** add new filter -> *has Taxonomy term ID* input the Active id, and now you are done.